# A single ViewModel with Carousel in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm currently developing an app trying to figure if one ViewModel is best for a carousel or if two ViewModels should be used. Currently, the carousel is actually two pages and if you swipe to the right, the second page is shown. Do I have a single ViewModel for the entire Carousel (both pages) or do I create separate ViewModels for both?

If I create separate ViewModels, how do I pass data from the first ViewModel to the second ViewModel on swipe? Would I need to add a custom behavior? (I have only recently researched behaviors and have not yet implemented one.) What would be best practice in this situation?

Comment: Just as a potential solution, it might be an option to implement Prism, and which means that every ViewModel has an `OnNavigatedTo()` and `OnNavigatedFrom()` method which do exactly as it says on the tin.